# Как сделать так что бы программа начала в определенным моменте цикла, ждать пользователя пока он не нажмет на кнопку

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.admin;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int level = 0;
    private int sum;
    private int x = 10, y = 1;
    private int NumberOfWrongAnswers = 0, NumberOfCorrectAnswers = 0;
    private int userNum;

    private String operator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }

    public static void times(int time){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
    }

    public void startGame(View v){
        Button btnTrue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonTrue);

        TextView lvl = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.levelid);
        lvl.setText(Integer.toString(level));

        TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.trueOtvet);
        score.setText
                (Integer.toString(NumberOfWrongAnswers) + " / " +Integer.toString(NumberOfCorrectAnswers));

        for(int a = 1; a <= 10; a++){
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
                int RandomNum1 = new Random().nextInt(x)+y;
                int RandomNum2 = new Random().nextInt(x)+y;
                int RandomFalseAnswer = new Random().nextInt(x)+y;
                int RandomPlusMinus = new Random().nextInt(2)+1;
                int RandomFalseTrue = new Random().nextInt(2)+1;

                if(RandomFalseTrue == 1) {
                    if (RandomPlusMinus == 1) {
                        operator = " + ";
                        sum = RandomNum1 + RandomNum2;
                    }
                    if (RandomPlusMinus == 2) {
                        operator = " - ";
                        sum = RandomNum1 - RandomNum2;
                    }
                }
                if(RandomFalseTrue == 2){
                    sum = RandomFalseAnswer;
                    if (RandomPlusMinus == 1) {
                        operator = " + ";
                    }
                    if (RandomPlusMinus == 2) {
                        operator = " - ";
                    }
                }

                TextView answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textEx);
                answer.setText
                        (Integer.toString(RandomNum1) + operator + Integer.toString(RandomNum2) + " = " + Integer.toString(sum));
                score.setText
                        (Integer.toString(NumberOfWrongAnswers) + " / " +Integer.toString(NumberOfCorrectAnswers));
                //_____________________________________
                btnTrue.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                userNum = 1;

                            }
                        }
                );
                // Ожидание игрока...
                //_____________________________________
                if ((userNum == 1 && RandomFalseTrue == 1) || (userNum == 2 && RandomFalseTrue == 2)){
                    NumberOfCorrectAnswers = NumberOfCorrectAnswers + 1;
                }
                else {
                    NumberOfWrongAnswers = NumberOfWrongAnswers + 1;
                }
            }
            level = level + 1;
            lvl.setText(Integer.toString(level));

            x = x * 10;
            y = y * 10;
        }
    }
}
// btnTrue должен ждать пользователя пока пользователь не нажмет на кнопка.
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно весь ваш код, который должен ждать нажатия кнопки вынести в отдельный поток в первую очередь. Потому что нельзя тормозить главный поток приложения. А после можно смотреть в сторону  синхронизаторо: `CountDownLatch`, `Semaphore`, `CyclicBarrier`

Comment: Я уже решил задачу. Я разделил цикл на две части, и если нажать на buttonTrue то он выполняет 2 часть цикла. После чего, опять переходит в первую часть цикла. Я вас не понял, можно было и по лучше сделать ?